# Запрет выделения текста в svg файле

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

У меня произошла проблема, при нажатии на элемент svg картинки, она должна заливаться зеленым, но при этом этому препятствует текст который хранится в сомой картинке. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить это
SVG файл (в нем нарисованы парковочные места):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW 2021 (64-Bit) -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="12mm" height="100mm" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 1200 10000"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <defs>
  <font id="FontID0" horiz-adv-x="666" font-variant="normal" style="fill-rule:nonzero" font-style="normal" font-weight="400">
    <font-face 
        font-family="Arial">
        <font-face-src>
            <font-face-name name="Arial"/>
        </font-face-src>
    </font-face>
   <missing-glyph><path d="M0 0z"/></missing-glyph>
   <glyph unicode="0" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M41.9993 353.333c0,84.5184 8.64553,152.832 25.9838,204.516 17.5273,51.826 43.3694,91.6521 77.6681,119.478 34.2042,27.8263 77.3374,41.6686 129.352,41.6686 38.3144,0 71.9989,-7.65342 101.148,-23.1492 29.0074,-15.4958 53.007,-37.8419 71.6682,-66.9911 18.6611,-29.0074 33.3538,-64.5344 44.0308,-106.345 10.8187,-41.8576 16.1572,-98.3607 16.1572,-169.178 0,-83.9987 -8.69278,-151.982 -25.8421,-203.666 -17.1493,-51.826 -42.9914,-91.6521 -77.3374,-119.667 -34.1569,-28.0153 -77.4791,-41.9993 -129.825,-41.9993 -68.8336,0 -123.022,24.5193 -162.328,73.6524 -47.1961,59.9991 -70.6761,157.179 -70.6761,291.68zm89.9986 -0.330703c0,-117.825 13.6533,-196.154 41.149,-234.847 27.5429,-38.834 61.5108,-58.1566 101.857,-58.1566 40.3458,0 74.3138,19.5115 101.809,58.3455 27.5429,38.9758 41.1962,117.164 41.1962,234.658 0,117.825 -13.6533,196.154 -41.1962,234.847 -27.3067,38.834 -61.6526,58.1566 -102.802,58.1566 -40.3458,0 -72.6603,-17.1493 -96.8489,-51.3535 -30.1413,-43.4639 -45.1646,-124.156 -45.1646,-241.65z"/>
   <glyph unicode="1" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M371.994 0l-88.0144 0 0 560.353c-21.165,-20.3619 -48.9914,-40.5348 -83.29,-60.7077 -34.3459,-20.1257 -65.3376,-35.2908 -92.6915,-45.3064l0 84.9908c49.1803,23.0075 92.1718,51.0228 129.022,83.9987 36.8026,32.8341 62.9754,64.6761 78.3295,95.6678l56.6448 0 0 -718.997z"/>
   <glyph unicode="2" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M503 83.9987l0 -83.9987 -473.993 0c-0.661407,21.165 2.8346,41.4797 10.3463,61.1801 12.1415,32.1727 31.653,63.9675 58.4873,95.1481 26.8342,31.1806 65.1486,67.18 114.99,107.998 77.4791,63.8258 130.155,114.329 157.651,151.651 27.6846,37.3695 41.5269,72.7075 41.5269,106.014 0,34.8183 -12.5195,64.1565 -37.5112,88.1561 -24.9917,23.8579 -57.6841,35.8577 -97.841,35.8577 -42.4718,0 -76.487,-12.6612 -101.998,-37.9837 -25.5114,-25.1807 -38.3144,-60.188 -38.6451,-105.022l-89.9986 9.02348c6.14164,67.3218 29.4799,118.628 69.8257,153.966 40.4876,35.338 94.6757,53.007 162.848,53.007 68.6446,0 123.163,-18.9918 163.131,-57.1645 40.1568,-38.1726 60.188,-85.5105 60.188,-141.825 0,-28.6767 -5.85818,-56.8338 -17.669,-84.5184 -11.6691,-27.8263 -31.1806,-56.9755 -58.3455,-87.6364 -27.3067,-30.5192 -72.4713,-72.7075 -135.494,-125.998 -52.8181,-44.3615 -86.8333,-74.361 -101.809,-90.1876 -15.0234,-15.8265 -27.3539,-31.653 -37.1805,-47.6685l351.491 0z"/>
   <glyph unicode="3" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M41.9993 190.013l88.0144 11.9998c10.1573,-50.0307 27.1649,-86.0301 51.3063,-107.998 24.1886,-22.0154 53.8574,-33.0231 89.0065,-33.0231 41.6686,0 76.8177,14.362 105.164,42.9914 28.346,28.6767 42.519,64.2037 42.519,106.534 0,40.2986 -13.1809,73.6524 -39.6844,99.9669 -26.3145,26.1728 -59.8101,39.3537 -100.676,39.3537 -16.6297,0 -37.3222,-3.35428 -62.1722,-9.82662l9.87386 77.0067c5.81093,-0.661407 10.6298,-1.03935 14.1258,-1.03935 37.7002,0 71.3375,9.87386 101.526,29.3381 29.9995,19.5115 44.9757,49.511 44.9757,89.9986 0,32.1727 -10.9605,58.8652 -32.8341,80.0302 -21.8264,21.165 -49.9835,31.653 -84.4711,31.653 -34.3459,0 -62.8337,-10.8187 -85.6522,-32.5034 -22.8658,-21.6375 -37.5112,-54.1409 -44.0308,-97.5103l-87.9671 16.0155c10.8187,59.0069 35.1491,104.833 73.3217,137.336 37.9837,32.5034 85.5105,48.6607 142.155,48.6607 39.023,0 75.0224,-8.31483 107.857,-25.1807 32.9759,-16.6297 58.1566,-39.4954 75.4949,-68.3139 17.48,-29.0074 26.1256,-59.6684 26.1256,-92.1718 0,-30.8499 -8.31483,-58.818 -24.8028,-84.1404 -16.6769,-25.3697 -41.3379,-45.5426 -73.8414,-60.5187 42.33,-9.68489 75.1642,-29.9995 98.6441,-60.8494 23.3382,-30.6609 35.0073,-69.306 35.0073,-115.51 0,-62.4557 -22.8185,-115.652 -68.3139,-159.163 -45.6843,-43.4639 -103.321,-65.1486 -173.005,-65.1486 -62.8337,0 -114.99,18.8501 -156.517,56.3141 -41.6686,37.5112 -65.3376,86.0301 -71.1485,145.698z"/>
   <glyph unicode="4" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M323.003 0l0 171.021 -311.003 0 0 80.9751 327.018 464.024 71.9989 0 0 -464.024 96.9906 0 0 -80.9751 -96.9906 0 0 -171.021 -88.0144 0zm0 251.996l0 322.152 -224.5 -322.152 224.5 0z"/>
   <glyph unicode="5" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M41.9993 187.981l91.9828 7.03926c6.85029,-44.8339 22.6768,-78.5184 47.3378,-101.195 24.661,-22.4878 54.8495,-33.8262 90.3293,-33.8262 42.8497,0 78.7074,16.0155 107.857,47.8575 29.0074,31.9837 43.5111,74.3138 43.5111,126.99 0,50.1724 -13.8423,89.6679 -41.6686,118.675 -27.8263,28.9602 -64.6761,43.4639 -110.502,43.4639 -28.535,0 -53.9991,-6.47234 -76.676,-19.4643 -22.4878,-13.0392 -40.1568,-29.8578 -53.1488,-50.5031l-83.0066 11.9998 68.9753 367.978 354.987 0 0 -83.9987 -284.83 0 -38.1254 -193.178c42.8025,30.1885 87.8254,45.1646 134.833,45.1646 62.314,0 114.99,-21.6375 157.793,-65.0069 42.8497,-43.3222 64.3454,-98.9748 64.3454,-166.958 0,-64.8651 -18.8029,-120.848 -56.503,-167.997 -45.826,-58.0148 -108.471,-87.0223 -187.84,-87.0223 -64.9596,0 -117.967,18.3304 -159.163,54.8495 -41.149,36.4719 -64.6761,84.8018 -70.4871,145.132z"/>
   <glyph unicode="6" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M498.984 540.984l-86.975 -6.99202c-7.8424,34.4876 -18.9918,59.6684 -33.4955,75.3531 -23.8579,25.1335 -53.3377,37.653 -88.3451,37.653 -28.157,0 -53.1488,-7.8424 -74.6917,-23.4799 -27.6374,-20.1729 -49.3221,-49.511 -65.4793,-88.2033 -16.0155,-38.834 -24.3303,-93.967 -24.9917,-165.493 21.165,32.1727 47.1489,56.1723 77.8098,71.6682 30.6609,15.6848 62.6919,23.5272 96.3292,23.5272 58.6762,0 108.707,-21.6847 150.045,-64.8651 41.149,-43.1332 61.7943,-98.8331 61.7943,-167.336 0,-44.9757 -9.63764,-86.6443 -29.0074,-125.337 -19.4643,-38.6451 -45.9678,-68.1249 -79.983,-88.6285 -33.8262,-20.5036 -72.3296,-30.8499 -115.321,-30.8499 -73.1799,0 -132.99,27.0232 -179.336,80.8334 -46.1568,53.8102 -69.3532,142.675 -69.3532,266.311 0,138.376 25.7004,239.004 76.8649,301.838 44.645,54.7078 104.833,82.0145 180.659,82.0145 56.3141,0 102.66,-15.8265 138.659,-47.3378 35.9994,-31.5113 57.6841,-74.9752 64.8179,-130.675zm-359.994 -308.972c0,-30.3302 6.51958,-59.3376 19.3225,-87.0223 12.8502,-27.6374 30.8499,-48.6607 53.6684,-63.1644 23.0075,-14.5037 47.3378,-21.8264 73.1799,-21.8264 37.5112,0 69.495,15.0234 95.9985,45.0229 26.5035,29.9995 39.8261,70.6288 39.8261,122.124 0,49.511 -13.1337,88.534 -39.3065,117.022 -26.1728,28.4877 -59.5266,42.8497 -100.014,42.8497 -39.6844,0 -73.5107,-14.362 -101.148,-42.8497 -27.6846,-28.4877 -41.5269,-65.8572 -41.5269,-112.156z"/>
   <glyph unicode="7" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M47.0071 622.998l0 83.9987 462.985 0 0 -67.9832c-45.4953,-48.5189 -90.8017,-113.006 -135.494,-193.509 -44.8339,-80.5027 -79.3216,-163.32 -103.841,-248.5 -17.48,-59.8573 -28.8184,-125.667 -33.6373,-197.005l-89.9986 0c0.99211,56.3141 11.9998,124.486 33.1648,204.327 21.165,79.983 51.3063,156.99 90.8017,231.162 39.4954,74.1721 81.4948,136.675 125.998,187.509l-349.979 0z"/>
   <glyph unicode="8" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M177.493 388.151c-36.4719,13.3699 -63.4951,32.5034 -81.1641,57.1645 -17.48,24.85 -26.3145,54.5188 -26.3145,89.0065 0,52.1567 18.6611,95.8568 55.9834,131.337 37.5112,35.527 87.164,53.3377 149.336,53.3377 62.314,0 112.675,-18.1414 150.659,-54.5188 37.9837,-36.3301 57.0227,-80.4554 57.0227,-132.659 0,-33.1648 -8.69278,-62.1722 -26.0311,-86.6443 -17.3383,-24.661 -43.6529,-43.6529 -79.1326,-57.0227 43.7946,-14.3147 76.9594,-37.3222 99.8252,-69.306 22.8185,-31.842 34.3459,-69.8257 34.3459,-114.187 0,-61.1801 -21.6847,-112.486 -64.8651,-154.155 -43.3222,-41.6686 -100.156,-62.503 -170.643,-62.503 -70.5343,0 -127.368,20.8343 -170.69,62.6447 -43.1804,41.8576 -64.8179,94.0143 -64.8179,156.517 0,46.4875 11.8108,85.5105 35.4798,116.833 23.6689,31.5113 57.3534,52.8181 101.006,64.1565zm-17.48 149.336c0,-33.968 10.8187,-61.6526 32.3145,-83.1483 21.6847,-21.4957 49.9835,-32.3617 85.1798,-32.3617 34.1569,0 61.8415,10.677 83.3373,32.031 21.4957,21.3068 32.1727,47.4796 32.1727,78.4712 0,32.3617 -11.0077,59.5266 -33.1648,81.542 -22.0154,21.9682 -49.8417,32.9759 -83.3373,32.9759 -33.8262,0 -61.6998,-10.8187 -83.668,-32.3145 -21.8264,-21.4957 -32.8341,-47.1961 -32.8341,-77.1956zm-29.0074 -330.987c0,-25.1807 5.81093,-49.3221 17.48,-72.8492 11.6691,-23.3382 29.3381,-41.4797 53.007,-54.3299 23.5272,-12.8029 48.8496,-19.3225 75.6838,-19.3225 42.33,0 77.0067,13.5116 104.172,40.4876 27.1649,27.0232 40.6293,61.3691 40.6293,102.991 0,42.3773 -13.984,77.3374 -41.8104,105.022 -28.0153,27.6846 -63.3533,41.4797 -105.825,41.4797 -41.6686,0 -75.8256,-13.6533 -102.849,-40.96 -26.976,-27.3539 -40.4876,-61.5108 -40.4876,-102.518z"/>
   <glyph unicode="9" horiz-adv-x="556" d="M54.9913 166.013l83.9987 6.99202c7.18099,-39.6844 20.8343,-68.3611 41.0072,-86.1719 20.1729,-17.8107 46.015,-26.8342 77.6681,-26.8342 27.0232,0 50.6449,6.18888 71.1485,18.6611 20.5036,12.3305 37.1805,28.8184 50.0307,49.6528 12.8029,20.6926 23.6689,48.7079 32.5034,83.8569 8.83451,35.1491 13.1337,71.0068 13.1337,107.479 0,3.87395 -0.14173,9.87386 -0.472434,17.669 -17.5273,-27.9681 -41.5269,-50.8338 -71.8571,-68.1722 -30.3302,-17.48 -63.3061,-26.1256 -98.6441,-26.1256 -59.1959,0 -109.179,21.4957 -150.187,64.4872 -40.8183,42.8497 -61.3219,99.4945 -61.3219,169.84 0,72.6603 21.354,131.006 64.1565,175.32 42.6607,44.1725 96.1875,66.3297 160.675,66.3297 46.3457,0 88.8175,-12.5195 127.51,-37.653 38.5033,-24.9917 67.6525,-60.6605 87.6364,-107.195 20.0312,-46.2985 30.0468,-113.479 30.0468,-201.304 0,-91.5104 -9.87386,-164.36 -29.6688,-218.5 -19.8422,-54.3299 -49.511,-95.5261 -88.6758,-123.825 -39.1647,-28.346 -84.9908,-42.519 -137.667,-42.519 -56.0306,0 -101.668,15.4958 -137.195,46.6764 -35.338,31.1334 -56.6448,74.9752 -63.8258,131.337zm359.002 315.822c0,50.3142 -13.3226,90.3293 -40.0151,119.809 -26.4563,29.5271 -58.818,44.3615 -96.8016,44.3615 -39.3537,0 -73.3217,-15.8265 -101.998,-47.6685 -28.8657,-31.842 -43.1804,-73.1799 -43.1804,-123.825 0,-45.4953 13.6533,-82.5341 40.8183,-110.833 27.3539,-28.535 61.3691,-42.6607 101.857,-42.6607 40.6765,0 73.9831,14.1258 100.156,42.6607 26.1728,28.2988 39.1647,67.8415 39.1647,118.156z"/>
   <glyph unicode="Б" horiz-adv-x="656" d="M81.0223 716.02l464.969 0 0 -83.9987 -370.01 0 0 -221.004 171.021 0c63.1644,0 113.337,-5.99991 150.659,-18.1887 37.3222,-11.9998 67.18,-34.6766 89.6679,-68.1722 22.4878,-33.3066 33.6845,-72.1406 33.6845,-116.502 0,-36.1412 -8.03137,-69.9674 -24.1886,-101.337 -16.1572,-31.4641 -40.1568,-57.1645 -72.1406,-77.0067 -31.842,-19.795 -86.3608,-29.8106 -163.179,-29.8106l-280.484 0 0 716.02zm94.9591 -634.998l189.54 0c51.1645,0 89.4789,10.2991 115.132,31.1334 25.5114,20.8343 38.3616,52.0149 38.3616,93.4946 0,29.6688 -7.36996,54.3299 -22.0154,74.1721 -14.6454,19.8422 -35.0073,33.0231 -60.9912,39.4954 -26.1728,6.51958 -70.6761,9.68489 -133.51,9.68489l-126.518 0 0 -247.98z"/>
  </font>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    @font-face { font-family:"Arial";font-variant:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;src:url("#FontID0") format(svg)}
    .str0 {stroke:#2B2A29;stroke-width:20;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
    .fil0 {fill:none}
    .fil1 {fill:#2B2A29}
    .fnt1 {font-weight:normal;font-size:211.59px;font-family:'Arial'}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:normal;font-size:211.67px;font-family:'Arial'}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 
 <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
   <g  transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -242.29 3856.38)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б14</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -246.13 3520.7)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б15</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -203.9 3152.25)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б16</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -203.9 2816.07)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б17</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -203.9 2488.1)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б18</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -208.22 2149.5)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б19</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -212.06 1813.83)">
   <text x="600" y="5000"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б20</text>
  </g>
  
  <rect id= "B14" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 8910.68)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B15" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 8579.29)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B16" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 8243.1)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B17" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 7906.92)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B18" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 7578.94)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B19" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 7246.18)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
  <rect id= "B20" class ="triger" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 6914.79)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
 
 
 </g>
</svg>
```

После чего я обрабатываю SVG файл через js:

```js
function choise_parkomesto(){
    var svgobject = document.getElementById('svg_parkomesta');
    if('contentDocument' in svgobject){
        var svgDocument = jQuery(svgobject.contentDocument);
        var mass=[];    
        $.ajax({
            url:'/php/login.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            charset: 'utf-8',
            success: function(data){
                mass = data.slice(0);
                mass.forEach(function(item, i, mass){
                        var mesto = "#"+ item
                        jQuery(mesto, svgDocument).attr("fill", "red");
                        jQuery(mesto, svgDocument).removeAttr('class', '');
                        
                });
            }

        });    
    }
     var svgobject1 = document.getElementById('svg_parkomesta');
      if('contentDocument' in svgobject1){
         var svgDocument1 = jQuery(svgobject1.contentDocument);
        var trigers = jQuery('.triger', svgDocument1);
        var trigers_id = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < trigers.length; i++){
            trigers[i].onclick = function(){
                trigers_id = this.id;
                Buffer = trigers_id;
                jQuery(this, svgDocument1).attr('fill', 'green');
                
            }
            
        } 
    }
}

window.onload = function(){    
    choise_parkomesto();
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru" xml:lang="ru">
  <head>
    <script src="js\code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="body">
        <div class ="form_box">
            <div class ="parkomesta">
                <object id="svg_parkomesta"  data="img/parkomesta.svg" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
            </div>   
            
            <script src="js\ajax.js"></script>
            <script src="js\Login.js?ver=1.0.38"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Проблема заключается в том что текст в квадрате мешает обрабатывать нажатие

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если поместить весь текст и фигуру в  и обращаться к нему, параллельно добавив в стили "user-select: none", то все отображается и работает так как нужно.
Пример:

```html
<svg>
<g  style="user-select: none;" class ="triger" id="B14">
   <rect id= "B14" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 8910.68)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
   <text x="600" y="5000" transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -242.29 3856.38)"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б14</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй указать свойство user-select: none для тегов text

Comment: Убрало выделение текста, но не помогло. Все ровно текст мешают нажатию

Comment: Попробуй text дать свойства position: relative; z-index: -1, а для rect тоже самое, но z-index: 1

Comment: Изменил svg файл по такому принципу:
 <g  style="user-select: none;" class ="triger" id="B14">
   <rect id= "B14" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" stroke-width="20" stroke-miterlimit= "22.9256" transform="matrix(2.81731E-14 -1.06376 1 -0.707045 242.66 8910.68)" width="314.74" height="674.68"/>
   <text x="600" y="5000" transform="matrix(1 -0.707045 0 1.06376 -242.29 3856.38)"  class="fil1 fnt0">Б14</text>
  </g>
Если обращаться через <g> то текст не мешает и никаких проблем нету